# How can I create a app that can be embeddable and use it as script in a React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, embedding, script-tag

I need to embed my own chatbot built using React in other React apps using `<script>`. Can anyone tell me where to start?

I need to do like this:

```
<script>
  window.chatbaseConfig = {
    chatbotId: "9hA3--GLvK_7q1DRscuH3",
  }
</script>
<script
  src="https://www.chatbase.co/embed.min.js"
  id="9hA3--GLvK_7q1DRscuH3"
  defer>
</script>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please see [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the `<iframe>` html tag? The iframe tag is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.
Here is more information [W3Schools iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP)

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) is widely considered a more canonical and reliable reference.

Comment: iframe is okay but i need in script only